# Why does dgroup not create equation numbers?

Tags: math-mode, breqn

I have a tex file:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
 \begin{dgroup}
  \begin{dmath*}
   0 = x + y
  \end{dmath*}
  \begin{dmath*}
   3 = 2x + 4y
  \end{dmath*}
 \end{dgroup}
\end{document}
```

I think, that `pdflatex` should produce two lines of equations with one common number on the right. But I do not get this number. In http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-3/tb56down.pdf on page 9/10 there is some example about that (the example code is from there). The official doc of `breqn` does not say it clearly, but I think it should work.

Can you tell me what's going wrong here? How to get the equation number correctly?

Besides: Are there "better packages" than `breqn`? I am used to use it as it breaks equations automatically which is very useful in case of narrow pages.

Comment: This looks like a `breqn` bug (@cmhughes you _should_ get a label for the entire group _if_ all of the equations within it are unnumbered). There is something up with the internal logic tests: I am investigating.

Comment: OK, I have tracked down the issue to a catcode problem. Regrettably, `breqn` is in something of a mess internally and this means that it's use of `expl3` is a bit 'odd'. I will need to track the problem back through the logs to work out why it has been introduced: I have a local fix but do not want to break something else. (The equation number prints in the wrong place, but that is a 'known issue'!)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
 \begin{dgroup*}
  \begin{dmath}
   0 = x + y
  \end{dmath}
  \begin{dmath}
   3 = 2x + 4y
  \end{dmath}
 \end{dgroup*}
\end{document}
```

`\begin{dmath*}` creates an equation without number...

`\begin{dgroup}` will introduce another numbering (subnumbering)

Comment: This creates separate numbers for each `dmath`, the OP wanted a single number for the entire `dgroup`, which he should have gotten according to the TUGboat article.

Comment: ok, so it seems to be unfinished (according to [documentation](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf))

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked for alternatives.